# Have a max height on a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [bootstrap-wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) editor.
I want to have max height. I don't want that each time I press enter the text start to go down or scrollable. I want a static 300px height. According to their docs I should do this.

```
#editor {overflow:scroll; max-height:300px}
```

But what it does is it add a scroll bar. That's because the overflow is set to scroll. If I removed it, it doesn't work.

I have my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/W8UQs/1/

Any idea how to stop the option of addinng the scrollbar, if the user overpass the max height it should be static, no scrollbar should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
#editor {overflow-y:auto; max-height:300px}
```

that will display a scrollbar only if you pass the max-height

If you want to avoid the scrollbar you can use

```
#editor {    max-height:300px;    height:300px;    overflow-y: hidden;}
```

That would require the arrow keys to scroll and can be a little confusing for the end user, but it's your call.

**Edit:**

If you want to hide any text that's below your div size and enforce the div showing the first line, I'm not sure it can be done with pure CSS, but you can use jQuery's scrollTop method to achieve that

```
$('#editor').on('keyup',function() {
    $('#editor').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. After you add some enters it add a scrollbar: http://screencloud.net/v/pVMV

Comment: Yes I noticed that. But I want to have the editor static. If the user pass the max-height it should stay that way. No scrollbar. No arrows. Just there.